# Can someone explain this JavaScript code please?

Tags: javascript, casting, return-value, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I am fairly beginner to JavaScript development and I would be obliged if someone could help explain this code to me.

```
m = function () {
 let t = e.getCookie("cli-analytics"),
     a = e.getCookie("cli-advertisement"),
     r = e.getCookie("CLI");
 return !(!t && !a) && { analytics: "yes" === t, ads: "yes" === a, visitorHasChosen: !!r };
}
```

I can understand the function assignment to the variable m and the cookie reads, but I have trouble understanding what the **return** actually does (returning an object ANDed with a complex logical NOT? Inside the object a property is assigned a double NOT?).
By the way is this good programming practice/writing?

Thanks to all

Comment: "_By the way is this good programming practice/writing?_" No. It looks like this code has been [minified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) and then reformatted again.

Comment: Apply DeMorgan's law to simplify the first conjunction operand into `(t || a)`, making the entire expression `(t || a) && { analytics: "yes" === t, ads: "yes" === a, visitorHasChosen: !!r }`, i.e. if either `t` or `a` exists/is truthy, return the object. By the way, `!!r` converts `r` into a boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, the code was first minified and then prettyfied again.

Thus one can comprehend the code's intension just from the *"speaking"* string values of the `getCookie` method. From there and from following the shortened variable names of `t`, `a` and `r` one can come up with own meaningful variable names and a substitution of the former by the latter.

Then, as already pointed to, one does apply name substitution and *DeMorgan's law* to the following expression ...

```
!(!t && !a)
```

1. `!(!analyticsValue && !advertisementValue)`

   - ... negation casts a value into a true boolean value, opposing the value's own truthy/falsy representation ... e.g. `!0 === true`, `!'' === true`, `!{} === false`.
2. `(!!analyticsValue || !!advertisementValue)`

   - ... double negation casts a value into a true boolean value of the value's own truthy/falsy representation ... e.g. `!!0 === false`, `!!'' === false`, `!!{} === true`.
3. `(analyticsValue || advertisementValue)`

   - ... a boolean operator on two values validates the expression by both of the values' truthy/falsy representations but returns the real value instead ... e.g. `(0 || 1) === 1`, `(2 || '') === 2` ... but `(2 && '') === ''`, `(2 && 3) === 3`, `('' && 3) === ''`.

... which for `2)` reads ... *"if either of the values exists (is `true`)"*

... and for `3)` ... *"if either of the values is truthy"*.

Since for the following restored example code it still is not clear where `e` does come from and what it means/represents, the example assumes a custom cookie `storage` which is treated as the function's sole parameter ...

```
/*
 * @returns {Object|false}
 *  either returns an object which features cookie values
 *  or returns the `false` boolean value.
 */
function getCliCookieValue(storage) {

  const analyticsValue = storage.getCookie('cli-analytics');
  const advertisementValue = storage.getCookie('cli-advertisement');

  // instead of ...
  return (!!analyticsValue || !!advertisementValue) && {

    analytics: 'yes' === analyticsValue,
    ads: 'yes' === advertisementValue,
    visitorHasChosen: !!storage.getCookie('CLI'),
  };

  // // ... one might consider ...
  // /*
  //  * @returns {Object|null}
  //  *  either returns an object which features cookie values
  //  *  or returns the `null` value.
  //  */
  // return (!!analyticsValue || !!advertisementValue) ? {
  // 
  //   analytics: 'yes' === analyticsValue,
  //   ads: 'yes' === advertisementValue,
  //   visitorHasChosen: !!storage.getCookie('CLI'),
  // 
  // } : null;
}
```

One could rewrite the above restored function to something more expressive / straightforward but of cause the computation process of the return value does not follow exactly the original one's, thus the return value for *falsy* intermediate values might differ in comparison with the original implementation.

```
/*
 * @returns {Object|false}
 *  either returns an object which features cookie values
 *  or returns the `false` boolean value.
 */
function getCliCookieValue(storage) {

  const isAnalytics = ('yes' === storage.getCookie('cli-analytics'));
  const isAdvertisement = ('yes' === storage.getCookie('cli-advertisement'));

  // instead of ...
  return (isAnalytics || isAdvertisement) && {

    analytics: isAnalytics,
    ads: isAdvertisement,
    visitorHasChosen: !!storage.getCookie('CLI'),
  };

  // // ... one might consider ...
  // /*
  //  * @returns {Object|null}
  //  *  either returns an object which features cookie values
  //  *  or returns the `null` value.
  //  */
  // return (isAnalytics || isAdvertisement) ? {
  // 
  //   analytics: isAnalytics,
  //   ads: isAdvertisement,
  //   visitorHasChosen: !!storage.getCookie('CLI'),
  // 
  // } : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this condition `!(!t && !a)` is satisfied, return `{ analytics: "yes" === t, ads: "yes" === a, visitorHasChosen: !!r }`

Answer (score 0):

### condition:

if one of `t` **or** `a` has a falsy value or both of them has a falsy value, return that `object`

### object:

the value of keys is a boolean type because comparing (===) or `!!`
so it checks if the value of `t` equal 'yes' then the value of `analytics` must be `true` otherwise `false`, also it's happening in `ads`

`!!r` in `visitorHasChosen` is Eqaul to `Boolean(r)`